# Countable union of sets of cardinality $c$ has cardinality $c$

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

The book Theory of Functions of a Real Variable by I. P. Natanson, proves that a denumerable or finite union of pairwise disjoint sets of cardinality $c$ has cardinality $c$.

The proofs given in the book are fairly easy, using the axiom of choice. But then it is left as an exercise a generalization of the above theorems for not necessarily pairwise disjoint sets.

I have searched all over the web, but all the proofs found so far are for pairwise disjoint sets.

The proof given in the book relies on the fact that each set $A_k$ can be matched with a set like $[a_{k-1},a_k)$, with $a_k$ point of a partition of $[0,1]$, such that $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty\lor n}A_k=[0,1)$. So it is easy to guess the bijective function, but I can't generalize this proof.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Let $B_1=A_1$. For $n\ge 2$ let $B_n=A_n\setminus\bigcup_{k=1}^{n-1}A_k$. Then $\bigcup_nB_n=\bigcup_nA_n$, the sets $B_n$ are pairwise disjoint, each has cardinality at most $\mathfrak{c}$, and $B_1$ has cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$.

Comment: I can prove that $\bigcup_nA_n\leq c$. How do I prove the opposite? Thanks.

Comment: @CABJ: $\left|\bigcup_nA_n\right|\ge\left|A_1\right|$.

Comment: I should have stated this above, but all I know about comparison of powers it that $|A|\leq |B|$ if $A\sim B^*\subset B$. The book doesn't develop a theory about cardinal numbers, instead proves theorem just using bijections and similar things...

Comment: @CABJ: By hypothesis $|A_1|=|Bbb R|$, and $A_1\subseteq\bigcup_nA_n$, so you have a bijection from $\Bbb R$ to a subset of $\bigcup_nA_n$; that’s enough to tell you that $\mathfrak{c}=|\Bbb R|\le\left|\bigcup_nA_n\right|$, and you already have the other inequality.

Comment: I'm a stupid, sorry. I wanted to say that I could prove $|\bigcup_nA_n|\geq c$, exactly as yo proved it above. The real problem is proving $|\bigcup_nA_n|\leq c$. Sorry again and thanks a lot.

Comment: @CABJ: That’s okay. To prove that, use the hint in my answer: replace $\bigcup_nA_n$ with $\bigcup_nB_n$, which is equal to it but a union of pairwise disjoint sets, and apply the result that you already know to the sets $B_n$.

Comment: I'm feeling like I'm asking too much of your help, but the result I already know is for sets of cardinality $c$, but some $B_n$ may not be countable nor having cardinal $c$ (I can't use the continuum hypothesis). I think maybe I can't prove this theorem using theorems proved in the book, instead need to get deeper in the theory of cardinal numbers...

Comment: @CABJ: The same method as in the theorem that you know will work as long as each of the sets has cardinality at most $\mathfrak{c}$. You won’t be able to get a bijection from $B_n$ to $[a_{n-1},a_n)$, but you will have an injection, which will give you an injection from $\bigcup_nB_n$ to $\Bbb R$; that’s good enough to give you the inequality that you want.

Comment: I got it. That's awesome! Thank you very much! Now everything is crystal clear.

Comment: @CABJ: You’re welcome! Glad we got it cleared up.